# Can I use custom component inside FieldArray using Formik

Tags: reactjs, forms, formik

If I replace Field component with normal input, the remove function behaves awkwardly.

Sample:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-formik-basic-example-27nly

Comment: I change `Field` with `input` and remove function there was no problem!

Comment: what do you mean by custom component ? Yes I observed the changes `Field` and `input` behaves differently

Comment: @AshishKamble: By Custom I mean using <CustomSelect name="xyz" /> instead of <Field name="xyz">

Comment: have to tried calling component `CustomSelect`? add that code too

Comment: See Formik [Field doc, section "component"](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/field), for how to specify the type of component you want the field to refer to. E.g., tell the Field you want it to be an "input". You can also specify any React component, including your own custom ones.